# Combinatorial Recursion 2

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Define a recursion $a(n,k)$ that gives the number of ways to choose $n$ items out of $k$ types of items, with the condition that we must choose $2, 4$, or $6$ items of each type.

So $2p+4q+6r = n$ and $p+q+r = k$ but as to the recursion I am lost. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the number of items of $k$th type that you pick. The other $n-m$ items are out of $k-1$ types. Thus, 
$$a(n,k)=a(n-2,k-1)+a(n-4,k-1)+a(n-6,k-1)  $$
which is the recursion you wanted.